# How did V get the financial resources to buy the the masks and deliver them without raising suspicion?

Tags: v-for-vendetta

V had masks and capes delivered to a large number of people in London:

From the scene (emphasis by me):

> Finch: *enters office*
>
> Finch: How many went out?
>
> Dominic: So far, we've count eight box cars. **Several hundred thousands**

He could not have ordered these masks within the UK, any producer would've rejected a request to do so (specially after the November 5th speech) for being too dangerous. So, he had to order it from abroad and import it into the UK. He could not import it legally. It is implied that it's more than eight box cars. Importing this via official means would raise suspicion at customs. He therefore needed help from organized crime and they rarely do a job "*pro bono*".

Furthermore, they needed to be delivered. The film implies they were delivered at the same day. A company might wonder if somebody wants to deliver a million or so parcels on the same date, it might even cost more as more people are required to deliver them.

Has it ever been explained how V got the financial resources to pay for all this? The only reasonable explanation I could come up with is that he stole and sold items like artworks. But that is rather difficult, looking at the amount:

Let's assume he needed a million masks / capes. With the price of a mask / cape / hat assumed to be £30, delivery and illegal import into the UK can be assumed around £15 per parcel and then another £15 per package for the delivery within the UK at the same day, we'd come around £60 per package, i.e. £60,000,000 costs. Getting that much money would require rather a lot of illegal activity, enough to ring alarm bells and massively heighten the chance of being caught.

Comment: Note that these parcels are being sent via the British Freight Company, presumably a fully nationalised version of Parcelforce. They seem more likely to have come from a supplier in the UK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the source comics, we learn that V has [access to the government's central computer, *Fate*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76664/20774), and has been using the tools of the state against itself. In the comic he orders government printers and postal services to deliver anti-government propaganda.

No mention is made of money, but the purpose of Fate is (amongst other things) to make and enforce economic decisions, so presumably it has its own unlimited credit card.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**V For Vendetta #08**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/V_for_Vendetta_Vol_1_8)</sup></sub>

In a world where asking too many of the wrong questions can get you 'disappeared', it would appear that the suppliers simply did what was asked of them.